# Why can I only place a bounty for 100+?

Tags: support, bounty

Attempting to put a bounty on one of my older [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56083/how-can-i-protect-my-buildings-against-creepers) too draw some new answers. Noticed it only gives me the option for 100+ rep bounties which I've never had happen to me. Not a big deal really just curious what happened to the 50 rep option.

I've combed through the FAQ pretty good didn't see anything related. Didn't see any duplicate questions.

[image]

Comment: I can bounty the question for 50, for what it's worth...

Comment: @badp hmmm, lemme get a screen shot in on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you have an answer on the question. You can't bounty for 50 on any question you have an answer on.

See [Minimum bounty on a question is now 100 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118706/minimum-bounty-on-a-question-is-now-100-rep), [Clever bounty reputation hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack/64826#64826)

Comment: Nice least this info will be a bit closer to home now.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [you can't bounty a question you self answered for 50 reputation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826/13992) The minimum bounty amount doubles with every successive self-answer bounty.

The idea is that such a bounty attracts upvotes to your answer *and* question and... it might just pay itself off. That's not how it should work.

Thanks for the assist, [Yannis Rizos](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/25936/yannis-rizos).

Comment: You're welcome!